# Nginx configurations for websockets

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm building a project and use websockets for the notifications.

If the backend is running in a docker container on my machine, the notifications work as expected. But on the server where Nginx is forwarding the websocket traffic to the docker container, it seems to work just once, after the client has started.

The notification that works is usually a pending notification that was stored as an unsent notification in the db.

I'm not sure if I can assume, that if a notification has been sent once, that the Nginx configuration is set correctly...

Can anybody verify if the configurations made to Nginx in /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite below is correct.

```
server {
    root /var/www/mywebsite.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:8080/;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:8080/ws;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; # for websockets
        # proxy_set_header Host $host; # for websockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1; # for websockets
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # for websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade"; # for websockets
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have tried to add additional lines of configs that are currently commented out with a #, but without success.